# how to use Distinct inside join in SQL

Tags: sql

```
select  e_id as 'آی‌دی', s_name as 'اسم',s_lastname as 'تخلص',e_mark as 'نمره',e_date as 'تاریخ',e_remarks as 'ملاحظات'from evaluation
join tblsalekin
on tblsalekin.s_id=evaluation.e_s_id
```

the above is my query, how do I add Distinct there?

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.  Also, what do YOU mean by "duplicate"?

Answer (score 1):

try like below for distinct

```
select distinct  e_id as 'آی‌دی', s_name as 'اسم',s_lastname as 'تخلص',e_mark as 'نمره',e_date as 'تاریخ',e_remarks as 'ملاحظات'
from evaluation e
join tblsalekin s
on s.s_id=e.e_s_id
```

using alias is good practice

Comment: provide sample data otherwise all brings mens what tough to understand

Comment: Then there is no any distinct values in your select combinations. Provide your sample data to analyse better

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin . . . I don't think a new user can downvote, even on the question that the person writes.